# How do I strip out a new line (\n) from my code in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have the following code (jQuery) in my view, and when title has a \n character then it breaks my js.

```
$("#t").html("#{title.html_safe}");
```

The following works but I think it's somewhat a hack:

```
$("#t").html("#{title.gsub("\n","")}");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [String#chomp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp). It will remove any carriage return characters from the end of your string.

```
$("#t").html("#{title.chomp}");
```

As always, only use `html_safe` if you are completely sure the `title` variable is safe... especially since you are using it within a Javascript file! I did not include it in my code example because I just couldn't bring myself to do it. Plus, see the note on [APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) in regards to using `html_safe` on a variable that could be `nil`. I would suggest only using it on a string literal.

EDIT:

If there is a chance that your `title` may contain quotes that need to be escaped before used in Javascript (for instance `'"Winter is Coming", I say'` which will interpolate into your javascript as `.html(""Winter is Coming", I say");`) then you should also use the [`escape_javascript`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/escape_javascript) method as suggested in the link @mu is too short provided.

```
$("#t").html("#{j(title.chomp)}");
```

If `title = '"Winter is Coming"'` then the above code would produce.

```
$("#t").html("\"Winter is Coming\"");
```

If there is also a chance that there is a carriage return in the middle of the title string, then `String#gsub` is the way to go.

```
$("#t").html("#{j(title.gsub(/[\n\r]/, " "))}");
```

I put a space in the second parameter of `gsub` so `'Winter\nis\nComing'` would become `'Winter is Coming'` and not `'WinterisComing'`.

Comment: And what happens when `title` is something like `'Is "Bobby Tables" Real?'`? Or if there are newlines in the middle of `title`?

Comment: With those considerations in mind, it almost sounds like there needs to be a helper method in place to handle many different situations (like backslashes as well). What suggestions might you have?

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel.  use the existing `escape_javascript` function.

Comment: @DGM I did suggest using the existing `escape_javascript`. I even provided a link to the documentation of it on APIdock. My comment about a helper method was _before_ my edit to the answer.

Comment: I just saw all the references to chomp.  the OP is asking a question that masks the real problem - I suspect they don't really want to remove newlines so much as make the javascript work.  The subject is misleading from the real problem

Comment: I ended up going with the j(title) solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are going to get less hacky

If you still want to have new lines, you could use `simple_format`

i.e. $("#t").html("#{simple_format title}");

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Though that also wraps it in a `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$("#t").html("#{title.html_safe}".chomp);
```

or shorter:

```
$("#t").html(title.html_safe.chomp);
```

This removes trailing newlines.

If you want to remove leading and trailing spaces you may replace `chomp` with `strip`.

If your text has newlines inside the string, the `gsub` solutions seems to be the right solution, but you don't need the `#{...}`:

```
$("#t").html(title.gsub("\n",""));
```

Comment: He does need the string interpolation because he is outputting Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

So many wrong answers.   Use [escape_javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript).

Comment: The OP wishes to remove carriage returns. Not escape them. This is why I suggested in my answer a removal of the carriage returns before passing the string into `j()`

Comment: The subject says that, but if you read the whole thing, this is to prevent the jquery line from breaking.  escape_javascript is the correct solution for the real problem at hand.